# Recursively list folders and subfolders from a network share and list members of the groups

Tags: powershell

unfortunately I'm not too well versed in powershell and my Google skills haven't fixed my problem yet.

So far I have to following script:

```
Get-childitem \\network\share\ -recurse | where{$_.psiscontainer} |
Get-Acl | % {
    $path = $_.Path
    $_.Access | % {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Folder = $path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::","")
            Access = $_.FileSystemRights
            Control = $_.AccessControlType
            User = $_.IdentityReference
            Inheritance = $_.IsInherited
            }
        }
    } | ? {-not $_.Inheritance} | export-csv output.csv -force
```

Which (partly) gives me the following output:

```
User                                       Folder
$DOMAIN\network_share_sub1_write            \\network\share\sub1
$DOMAIN\network_share_sub1_read             \\network\share\sub1
$DOMAIN\network_share_sub1_subsub1_write    \\network\share\sub1\subsub1
$DOMAIN\network_share_sub2_write            \\network\share\sub2
```

The problem here is that I have to look up each group to see the respective users. What I'd like to have is something like this:

```
User    Permission Folder
$User1   write      \\network\share\sub1
$User2   read       \\network\share\sub1
$User3   write      \\network\share\sub1\subsub1
$User1   write      \\network\share\sub2
```

Is something like this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to suggest a definitive answer, but I'd use the $_.IdentityReference in the ACLs and check AD with some AD commandlets to see if they're groups, and if so, get the members of the groups.  Hopefully that gets you started.

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-childitem \\network\share\ -recurse | where{$_.psiscontainer} |
Get-Acl | % {
    $path = $_.Path
    $_.Access | % {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Folder = $path.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::","")
            Access = $_.FileSystemRights
            Control = $_.AccessControlType
            User = $_.IdentityReference
            Inheritance = $_.IsInherited
            }
        }
    } | select-object -Property User, Access, Folder | export-csv output.csv -force
```

**select-object -Property User, Access, Folder**
The code will rearrange the order, you will see what you want.

```
User    Permission Folder
$User1   write      \\network\share\sub1
$User2   read       \\network\share\sub1
$User3   write      \\network\share\sub1\subsub1
$User1   write      \\network\share\sub2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this script https://jfrmilner.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/audit-ntfs-permissions-powershell-script/ which helped me a lot, and to edit it per your choice.

For example, I only wanted to go two levels in depth, so I changed line 11 of the Get-PathPermissions.ps1 to be:

```
$containers = Get-ChildItem -path $Path,$Path\*\* | ? {$_.psIscontainer -eq $true}
```

Also, you can sort your Folders with `Sort-Object Path` so you have a a complete hierarchy from top to the desired folder (specified by depth). Let's say, if you want to go three levels deep, and not two, it should be like this `Get-ChildItem -path $Path,$Path\*\*,$Path\*\*\*` and so on..